# execute() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: sql, python-3.x, typeerror

I am getting the TypeError in the title and not quite sure why.  Following [DB-API’s parameter substitution](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) this should be working fine.

This is for a conversion website that I am working on.  I am using a base unit multipliers to convert one unit to another. So for example centimeter to yard would look like this.

amount = user input to be converted

row_1 = user selected first base unit multiplier (cm to meter)

row_2 = user selected second base multiplier (meter to yard)

conversion_results = amount * row_1 * row_2⁻¹

I have tried '%s" but understand that that puts me at risk so the below is what I am currently stuck on.  I am working on Python 3 and phpLiteAdmin for the SQL table.

**EDIT**  I have tried to simply input a string, for example (Metre,), ("Metre",), (Metre), and ("Metre") and I am still getting the same error.  I have added pictures of my SQL table because maybe something is wrong with it?

[image: Structure of my table]
[image: Contents of my table]

```
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, 
url_for
from flask_session import Session
from passlib.apps import custom_app_context as pwd_context
from tempfile import gettempdir

from helpers import *
db = SQL("sqlite:///countertapp.db")    

@app.route("/length", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def length():

if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("length.html")

if request.method == "POST":

    amount = request.form.get("amount")

    if not amount:
        return apology("Enter some numbers")
    elif amount.isalpha():
        return apology("No letters please")
    elif any(c.isalpha() for c in amount):
        return apology("I said no letters!")

    convert_from = request.form.get("unit_1")
    convert_to = request.form.get("unit_2")


    row_1 = db.execute("SELECT bum FROM conversion WHERE unit = ?", (convert_from,))
    row_2 = db.execute("SELECT bum FROM conversion WHERE unit = ?", (convert_to,))

    conversion_result = int(amount) * row_1[0]["bum"] * row_2[0]["bum"]**-1

    return render_template("length_converted.html", result = conversion_result )
```

Comment: Probably need to escape those commas I'd gander the parsing engine is interpreting them as delimiters for additional arguments (hence the error).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it.  I tried earlier without the comma and with and without the parentheses as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use the semicolon. The below works.

```
row_1 = db.execute("SELECT bum FROM conversion WHERE unit = :id", id = 
request.form.get("unit_1"))
row_2 = db.execute("SELECT bum FROM conversion WHERE unit = :id", id = 
request.form.get("unit_2"))
```